# Bootstrap list-inline is not Functioning in <pre> Box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/rwrk5/) and let me know why BootStrap `list-inline` class is not functioning inside a `<pre></pre>` box?

```
 <pre>
  <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">One </a></li>
      <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Two </a></li>
      <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Threew </a></li>
  </ul>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not valid HTML in the first place. Running your code through html5.validator.nu yields:

> Error: Element `ul` not allowed as child of element `pre` in this context.
>   From line 8, column 3; to line 8, column 26:
>   "`>↩<pre>↩  <ul class="list-inline">↩`"
>
> Contexts in which element `ul` may be used:
>
> - Where [flow content](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#flow-content-1) is expected.
>
> Content model for element `pre`:
>
> - [Phrasing content](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#phrasing-content-1).